# Turn visited website hyperlink to purple

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

By default any link I visit on google turns purple on most browsers. This only applies to the specific webpages I visit. Is there any way to turn links for all webpages of a particular website purple if I visit just one webpage of that website?

For instance if i go to facebook page for eminem 
*https://www.facebook.com/eminem/*  turns purple

But I want **all** facebook links like 
*https://www.facebook.com/EdSheeranMusic/* to turn purple too.

Is there a script/addon? Any pointers how I can make a script for this (preferably for firefox)?

Comment: My suggestion is, edit the post and add the Website's name so that we can also try what is going on or add some Screen Shots.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have rolled back the edit. My problem isn't unusual behavior. I need an addon/script for an additional feature. When I visit a webpage link it turns purple like it is supposed to. What I want is for all links to that website ( not webpage ) to turn purple as well.

Comment: Truly I've misinterpreted the issue, feeling sorry for that !

Comment: You were trying to help :) I should have been more clear.

Comment: Why do you want to display them as visited when those pages were not actually visited?

Answer (score 0):

The logic to mark links as visited is a basic part of browsers and, at least as far as I know, there is no web-exposed API to get or change the visited state of links due to security/privacy reasons.

This limitation may not apply to browser extensions, though as outlined in the [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396422/432681).

Nonetheless there may be a JavaScript solution to your problem. For this to work you have to add a click event listener to every link on your page. So when you click a link, the listener goes through all other links and adds a `visited` class to the ones that have the same domain as the clicked link.
Downside is that the state is not saved, i.e. once you refresh the page the `visited` class is removed again.